# E-Mail Validation Error in PHP All-in-One Form

Tags: php, validation, email

I was doing an exercise from a book and copied exactly what was in there (to my knowledge) yet I still can't get it to process a valid E-Mail. I've tried different regular expressions but have had no luck. I'm pretty sure I missed something stupid (and sound pretty stupid asking for this but I am new to PHP). Can anyone take a look and see if you can see what I'm missing (or doing wrong)?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
       <head>
       <title>Contact Me</title>
       </head>
       <header>
       </header>
       <body>
       <?php
    function validateInput($data, $fieldName) {
    global $errorCount;
    if (empty($data)) {
        echo "\"$fieldName\" is a required field.<br />\n";
        ++$errorCount;
        $retval = "";
    } else {
        $retval = trim($data);
        $retval = stripslashes($retval);
        }
    return($retval);
    }
    
    
function validateEmail($data, $fieldName) {
    global $errorCount;
    if(empty($data)) {
        echo "\"$fieldName\" is a required field.<br />\n";
        ++$errorCount;
        $retval = "";
    } else {
        $retval = trim($data);
        $retval = stripslashes($retval);
        $pattern = "/^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@" . "[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*" . "(\.[[a-z]]{2,})$/i";
        if (preg_match($pattern, $retval)==0) {
            echo "\"$fieldName\" is not a valid e-mail address.<br />\n";
            ++$errorCount;
            }
        }
    return($retval);
}

function displayForm($Sender, $Email, $Subject, $Message) {
?>
<h2 style = "text-align:center">Contact Me</h2>
<form name=contact: action="ContactForm.php" method="post">
<p>Your Name: <input type="text" name="Sender" value="<?php echo $Sender; ?>" /></p>
<p>Your E-mail: <input type="text" name="Email" value="<?php echo $Email; ?>" /></p>
<p>Subject: <input type="text" name="Subject" value="<?php echo $Subject; ?>" /></p>
<p>Message: <br />
<textarea name="Message"><?php echo $Message; ?></textarea></p>
<p><input type="reset" value="Clear Form" />&nbsp;
&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send Form" /></p>
</form>
<?php
}

$showForm = TRUE;
$errorCount = 0;
$Sender = "";
$Email = "";
$Subject = "";
$Message = "";

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $Sender = validateInput($_POST['Sender'], "Your Name");
    $Email = validateEmail($_POST['Email'], "Your Email");
    $Subject = validateInput($_POST['Subject'], "Subject");
    $Message = validateInput($_POST['Message'], "Message");
    if($errorCount==0)
        $showForm = FALSE;
    else
        $showForm = TRUE;
    }
    
if ($showForm == TRUE) {
    if ($errorCount>0)
        echo "<p>Please re-enter the form information below.</p>\n";
        displayForm($Sender, $Email, $Subject, $Message);
}
else {
    $SenderAddress = "$Sender <$Email>";
    $Headers = "From: $SenderAddress\n CC: $SenderAddress\n";
    $result = mail("greg.englar@gmail.com", $Subject, $Message, $Headers);
    if ($result)
        echo "<p>Your message has been sent. Thank you, " . $Sender . ".</p>\n";
    else
        echo "<p>There was an error sending your message, " . $Sender . ".</p>\n";
    }
?>
</body> 
 </html>
```

I think I have a good grasp as to what the code is doing and how it is working but I am clearly missing something. It doesn't accept any E-Mail as valid and always shows an error message. For reference the book I'm using is "PHP Programming with MySQL Second Edition" by Don Gosselin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error in the regular expression. Should be `[a-z]` instead of `[[a-z]]` at the end